# How to Manage Wifi Clients in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, application-development, network-manager, client

I'm looking for an application to manage clients who are connected to my Wifi.
that application what I can see online clients, and can disconnect them after example 1 hour..is there any application to do this in Ubuntu?
In other work..is there any command in Ubuntu I disconnect Clients by their IP address after 1 hour?

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes change the parameters of the client DHCP lease in your wireless router settings. The DHCP lease, by default, is usually about 20 hours and can be set to expire sooner, later, or never. If this option is available, you can certainly set it to expire in one hour.

Comment: You might want to check out [DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) after-market firmware for your router. Be sure to read up on all the instructions before starting so you don't brick your router.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't support my device

Comment: You could try [Tomato by Shibby](http://tomato.groov.pl/?page_id=164) . . . just make sure to download the one with -En for English instead of -Pl unless you understand Polish, and again, make sure to follow the Wiki instructions so you don't brick your router.

Comment: Shibby has made some firmware that is not available on DDWRT so it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

## Scan clients on wifi network using `arp-scan` tool

- Command to install `arp-scan`

  `sudo apt-get install arp-scan`
- command to scan for wifi clients would be like this

  `sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet`

  Please  refer  to this [**page**](http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools-resources/security-tools/arp-scan) for more information.

Comment: arp-scan only shows clients ip and mac address, what I'm looking for is to disconnect one client from Wifi automatically..something like command..thanks for reply